# How can I install/use "Scripting.FileSystemObject" in Excel 2010 for MAC?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using **Excel for Mac 2011** which has VBA version 14.0.

I am trying to use this code which accesses the **file system**, which I know works on Windows:

```
Function qfil_GetDirectory(strDirectoryName As String)

    Dim objFSO As Variant
    Dim objDirectory As Variant

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objDirectory = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectoryName)
    Set qfil_GetDirectory = objDirectory

End Function
```

However, when I run it in Excel for Mac 2011, it gives me this **error**:

> Run-time error 429 Object creation
>   with ActiveX component not possible

To fix this on Windows, I know I have to just reference a specific **DLL** under tools.

However on the Mac, when I go under **tools | references** it **only** gives me these:

[image]

And none of them allow me to use `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

**What do I have to do in Excel 2011 for Mac so that I can use Scripting.FileSystemObject to read files from the hard drive from an Excel sheet via VBA?**

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, this approach won't be valid on Mac, as the external library doesnt exist.

Don't know Office 11 VBA, but the Dir() function works accross platforms for '03.

Answer (score 1):

What about...?
[Writing mac compatible file i o code in vba](http://illcode.org/post/14265165805/writing-mac-compatible-file-i-o-code-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Mac doesn't support ActiveX (it's a Windows technology), so you can't create the Scripting.FileSystemObject; it doesn't exist. (Even if it did, it's based on FAT32 or NTFS file systems, so it wouldn't work on OS X anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to enumerate all the files in a folder, [Codematic](http://www.codematic.net/excel-tools/office-2007-filesearch.htm) have a pretty good VBA module which should work fine on the Mac. It's not free, though.