# Is there an alternative to Scripting.FileSystemObject in Excel 2011 VBA for the mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, filesystemobject

The answers to [How can I install/use “Scripting.FileSystemObject” in Excel 2011 for MAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670420/how-can-i-install-use-scripting-filesystemobject-in-excel-2010-for-mac/4673429#4673429) seem to indicate that using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in Excel 2010 for the mac is **not** possible.

What other **alternative** is available so I can:

- get a **collection** of all Excel files in a specific directory
- **iterate** through each worksheet within each file and export it to a **.csv** file

Currently this is a **six-step** process for each file:

```
--how to create CSV files for all worksheets in a file:
1. open file
2. click "Developer"
3. click editor
4. click ThisWorkbook
5. copy in:
Sub save_all_csv()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ExcelFileName As String
    ExcelFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    For Each objWorksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Filename = "FILE-" & ExcelFileName & "-WORKSHEET-" & objWorksheet.Name & ".csv"
        objWorksheet.SaveAs Filename:="Macintosh HD:Users:edward:Documents:temporaryNoBackup:" & Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
6. click run (it closes by itself)
```

I'm looking for a way to **automate** this on the Mac, ideally, a (cron job?, service?) would open the excel file every 10 minutes, which would in turn look in a directory, convert all the other Excel files to .csv files, and then close by itself.

**Without Scripting.FileSystemObject, how can I make this Excel-to-CSV conversion fully automatic on the Mac?**

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is using the "Dir" function.  Since mac supports extra characters in their filenames, wildcards do not work with the "Dir" function.  Here is a sample.

```
Function GetFileList(folderPath As String) As Collection
'mac vba does not support wildcards in DIR function

    Dim file As String
    Dim returnCollection As New Collection

    If Right$(folderPath, 1) <> "/" Then
        folderPath = folderPath & "/"
    End If

    file = Dir$(folderPath) 'setup initial file

    Do While Len(file)
        returnCollection.Add folderPath & file
        file = Dir$
    Loop

    Set GetFileList = returnCollection
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the VBA in an add-in (.xlam file) that is attached to Excel itself, rather than the workbook. For your example code, the only modification would be to write against `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Sub save_all_csv()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ExcelFileName As String
    ExcelFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    For Each objWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Filename = "FILE-" & ExcelFileName & "-WORKSHEET-" & objWorksheet.Name & ".csv"
        objWorksheet.SaveAs Filename:="Macintosh HD:Users:edward:Documents:temporaryNoBackup:" & Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

You can also leverage auto_open() to automate binding a hotkey. Once that's done, you can just open a workbook, press a hotkey, and get your CSV files.

```
Public Sub auto_open()

'   Register hotkeys

'   See key codes here
'   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-onkey-method-excel

'   ^ = CTRL
'   % = ALT
'   + = SHIFT

    Application.OnKey "^+e", "save_all_csv" ' Ctrl+Shift+E will call save_all_csv()

End Sub
```