# How can I convert "Western (Mac OS Roman)" formatted text to UTF-8 with PHP?

Tags: php, macos, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

I have files being exported by Excel for Mac 2011 VBA in **Western (Mac OS Roman)** as shown here:

[image]

I haven't been successful in [getting Excel for Mac VBA to export directly to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722716/how-to-save-worksheets-as-csv-files-in-utf-8-format-with-excel-for-mac-2011) so I want to convert these files with PHP before I save them to MySQL, I am using this command:

```
$dataset[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8'); //not correctly converted
$dataset[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'ISO-8859-8', 'UTF-8'); //not correctly converted
$dataset[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'macintosh', 'UTF-8'); //unrecognized name
$dataset[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8'); //changes "schön" to "schљn"
$dataset[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'); //changes "schön" to "schšn"
```

I found this [list of valid encoding formats](http://www.eatmybusiness.com/food/2008/01/30/list-of-accepted-encodings-that-can-be-passed-to-mb_convert_encoding-as-arguments/63/) from 2008, but none of them seem to represent `Western (Mac OS Roman)`.

```
* UCS-4
* UCS-4BE
* UCS-4LE
* UCS-2
* UCS-2BE
* UCS-2LE
* UTF-32
* UTF-32BE
* UTF-32LE
* UTF-16
* UTF-16BE
* UTF-16LE
* UTF-7
* UTF7-IMAP
* UTF-8
* ASCII
* EUC-JP
* SJIS
* eucJP-win
* SJIS-win
* ISO-2022-JP
* JIS
* ISO-8859-1
* ISO-8859-2
* ISO-8859-3
* ISO-8859-4
* ISO-8859-5
* ISO-8859-6
* ISO-8859-7
* ISO-8859-8
* ISO-8859-9
* ISO-8859-10
* ISO-8859-13
* ISO-8859-14
* ISO-8859-15
* byte2be
* byte2le
* byte4be
* byte4le
* BASE64
* HTML-ENTITIES
* 7bit
* 8bit
* EUC-CN
* CP936
* HZ
* EUC-TW
* CP950
* BIG-5
* EUC-KR
* UHC (CP949)
* ISO-2022-KR
* Windows-1251 (CP1251)
* Windows-1252 (CP1252)
* CP866 (IBM866)
* KOI8-R
```

**What format do I need to use to convert "Western (Mac OS Roman) to UTF-8?**

Comment: Have you tried with [iconv](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) yet?

Comment: C++ code/table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022902/384670

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The mb-functions can't handle "macintosh" which is the IANA defined name for Mac Roman. You have to use `iconv`.

```
$line = iconv('macintosh', 'UTF-8', $line);
```