# Converting Mac Roman character to equivalent UTF-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings, mac-roman

I have been given some HTML files that use the Mac OS Roman file encoding.  The files have French text, but in an editor many of the diacritical chars look strange (i.e. non French)

```
Si cette option est sÈlectionnÈe, <removed> tentera de communiquer avec votre tÈlescope seulement ‡ líaide díun ...
```

The capital E with accent does display properly in the browser as é as do the other strange characters.

I also have some UTF-8 French files that look normal in an editor (é looks like é).  What I'd like to do is convert all the Mac Roman files to UTF-8 for easier maintenance.

Simply changing the file encoding in the editor doesn't do this.  The strange characters are still strange.

Short of making a conversion dictionary and doing a Find/Replace on all the files, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your editor isn’t showing it correctly when you specify the encoding, you have given it the wrong encoding. You need to figure what encoding you really have.

You appear to have a byte valued 0xE9 where you need a Unicode  `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` character.  A MacRoman 0xE9 byte is a `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE` character, which is what your editor is displaying because you said it was MacRoman.  But it is not.

However, Unicode code point U+00E9 is indeed `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`.

Therefore, it is **not** MacRoman that you have there, but almost certainly ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15.

So use something like

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 < input.latin1 > output.utf8
```

to do the conversion.

Answer (score 9):

*To actually answer the question "**Converting Mac Roman character to equivalent UTF-8**"*

Convert the encoding of the file from Mac OS Roman to UTF-8:

```
$ iconv -f macintosh -t UTF-8 < INPUT_FILE_PATH > OUTPUT_FILE_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert lots of old java code files in directory tree, this worked for me. 
Observe that the command will change files recursively in all directories from where you did cd into. Make sure you are positioned in the right directory and that you have a backup of your files, and computer, first. When you know what you are doing, correct the rm statement. Hope this can help somebody, took me hours to correct the tiny details to get this working.:

```
cd /tmp  
pwd  
find . -name "*.java" -exec bash -c 'mv $1 $1.WXY; iconv -f MAC -t UTF8 $1.WXY > $1; rm $1.WXYY' sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ code:

```
string ConvertMacRomanCharacterToUtf8( unsigned char c )
{
    static vector<string> strings
    // switch ( c )
    {
        /* case 0x80: return */ "\xC3\x84", // A umlaut
        /* case 0x81: return */ "\xC3\x85", // A circle
        /* case 0x82: return */ "\xC3\x87", // C cedilla
        /* case 0x83: return */ "\xC3\x89", // E accent
        /* case 0x84: return */ "\xC3\x91", // N tilde
        /* case 0x85: return */ "\xC3\x96", // O umlaut
        /* case 0x86: return */ "\xC3\x9C", // U umlaut
        /* case 0x87: return */ "\xC3\xA1", // a accent
        /* case 0x88: return */ "\xC3\xA0", // a grave
        /* case 0x89: return */ "\xC3\xA2", // a circumflex
        /* case 0x8A: return */ "\xC3\xA4", // a umlaut
        /* case 0x8B: return */ "\xC3\xA3", // a tilde
        /* case 0x8C: return */ "\xC3\xA5", // a circle
        /* case 0x8D: return */ "\xC3\xA7", // c cedilla
        /* case 0x8E: return */ "\xC3\xA9", // e accent
        /* case 0x8F: return */ "\xC3\xA8", // e grave

        /* case 0x90: return */ "\xC3\xAA", // e circumflex
        /* case 0x91: return */ "\xC3\xAB", // e umlaut
        /* case 0x92: return */ "\xC3\xAD", // i accent
        /* case 0x93: return */ "\xC3\xAC", // i grave
        /* case 0x94: return */ "\xC3\xAE", // i circumflex
        /* case 0x95: return */ "\xC3\xAF", // i umlaut
        /* case 0x96: return */ "\xC3\xB1", // n tilde
        /* case 0x97: return */ "\xC3\xB3", // o accent
        /* case 0x98: return */ "\xC3\xB2", // o grave
        /* case 0x99: return */ "\xC3\xB4", // o circumflex
        /* case 0x9A: return */ "\xC3\xB6", // o umlaut
        /* case 0x9B: return */ "\xC3\xB5", // o tilde
        /* case 0x9C: return */ "\xC3\xBA", // u accent
        /* case 0x9D: return */ "\xC3\xB9", // u grave
        /* case 0x9E: return */ "\xC3\xBB", // u circumflex
        /* case 0x9F: return */ "\xC3\xBC", // u tilde

        /* case 0xA0: return */ "\xE2\x80\xA0", // cross
        /* case 0xA1: return */ "\xC2\xB0", // degree
        /* case 0xA2: return */ "\xC2\xA2", // cents
        /* case 0xA3: return */ "\xC2\xA3", // pounds
        /* case 0xA4: return */ "\xC2\xA7", // section
        /* case 0xA5: return */ "\xE2\x80\xA2", // bullet
        /* case 0xA6: return */ "\xC2\xB6", // pilcrow
        /* case 0xA7: return */ "\xC3\x9F", // german sharp S
        /* case 0xA8: return */ "\xC2\xAE", // registered
        /* case 0xA9: return */ "\xC2\xA9", // copyright
        /* case 0xAA: return */ "\xE2\x84\xA2", // TM
        /* case 0xAB: return */ "\xC2\xB4", // back tick
        /* case 0xAC: return */ "\xC2\xA8", // umlaut
        /* case 0xAD: return */ "\xE2\x89\xA0", // not equal (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xAE: return */ "\xC3\x86", // AE
        /* case 0xAF: return */ "\xC3\x98", // O slash

        /* case 0xB0: return */ "\xE2\x88\x9E", // infinity (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB1: return */ "\xC2\xB1", // plus or minus
        /* case 0xB2: return */ "\xE2\x89\xA4", // less than or equal (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB3: return */ "\xE2\x89\xA5", // greater than or equal (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB4: return */ "\xC2\xA5", // yen
        /* case 0xB5: return */ "\xC2\xB5", // mu
        /* case 0xB6: return */ "\xE2\x88\x82", // derivative (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB7: return */ "\xE2\x88\x91", // large sigma (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB8: return */ "\xE2\x88\x8F", // large pi (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xB9: return */ "\xCF\x80", // small pi (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xBA: return */ "\xE2\x88\xAB", // integral (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xBB: return */ "\xC2\xAA", // feminine ordinal
        /* case 0xBC: return */ "\xC2\xBA", // masculine ordinal
        /* case 0xBD: return */ "\xCE\xA9", // large ohm (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xBE: return */ "\xC3\xA6", // ae
        /* case 0xBF: return */ "\xC3\xB8", // o slash

        /* case 0xC0: return */ "\xC2\xBF", // inverted question mark
        /* case 0xC1: return */ "\xC2\xA1", // inverted exclamation mark
        /* case 0xC2: return */ "\xC2\xAC", // not
        /* case 0xC3: return */ "\xE2\x88\x9A", // root (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xC4: return */ "\xC6\x92", // function
        /* case 0xC5: return */ "\xE2\x89\x88", // approximately equal (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xC6: return */ "\xE2\x88\x86", // large delta (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xC7: return */ "\xC2\xAB", // open angle quotation mark
        /* case 0xC8: return */ "\xC2\xBB", // close angle quotation mark
        /* case 0xC9: return */ "\xE2\x80\xA6", // ellipsis
        /* case 0xCA: return */ "\xC2\xA0", // NBSP
        /* case 0xCB: return */ "\xC3\x80", // A grave
        /* case 0xCC: return */ "\xC3\x83", // A tilde
        /* case 0xCD: return */ "\xC3\x95", // O tilde
        /* case 0xCE: return */ "\xC5\x92", // OE
        /* case 0xCF: return */ "\xC5\x93", // oe

        /* case 0xD0: return */ "\xE2\x80\x93", // en dash
        /* case 0xD1: return */ "\xE2\x80\x94", // em dash
        /* case 0xD2: return */ "\xE2\x80\x9C", // open smart double quote
        /* case 0xD3: return */ "\xE2\x80\x9D", // close smart double quote
        /* case 0xD4: return */ "\xE2\x80\x98", // open smart single quote
        /* case 0xD5: return */ "\xE2\x80\x99", // close smart single quote
        /* case 0xD6: return */ "\xC3\xB7", // divided
        /* case 0xD7: return */ "\xE2\x97\x8A", // diamond (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xD8: return */ "\xC3\xBF", // y umlaut
        /* case 0xD9: return */ "\xC5\xB8", // Y umlaut
        /* case 0xDA: return */ "\xE2\x81\x84", // big slash (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xDB: return */ "\xE2\x82\xAC", // euro (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xDC: return */ "\xE2\x80\xB9", // open angle single quote
        /* case 0xDD: return */ "\xE2\x80\xBA", // close angle single quote
        /* case 0xDE: return */ "\xEF\xAC\x81", // fi ligature (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xDF: return */ "\xEF\xAC\x82", // fl ligature (not in Windows 1252)

        /* case 0xE0: return */ "\xE2\x80\xA1", // double dagger
        /* case 0xE1: return */ "\xC2\xB7", // interpunct
        /* case 0xE2: return */ "\xE2\x80\x9A", // inverted smart single quote
        /* case 0xE3: return */ "\xE2\x80\x9E", // inverted smart double quote
        /* case 0xE4: return */ "\xE2\x80\xB0", // per mille
        /* case 0xE5: return */ "\xC3\x82", // A circumflex
        /* case 0xE6: return */ "\xC3\x8A", // E circumflex
        /* case 0xE7: return */ "\xC3\x81", // A accent
        /* case 0xE8: return */ "\xC3\x8B", // E umlaut
        /* case 0xE9: return */ "\xC3\x88", // E grave
        /* case 0xEA: return */ "\xC3\x8D", // I accent
        /* case 0xEB: return */ "\xC3\x8E", // I circumflex
        /* case 0xEC: return */ "\xC3\x8F", // I umlaut
        /* case 0xED: return */ "\xC3\x8C", // I grave
        /* case 0xEE: return */ "\xC3\x93", // O accent
        /* case 0xEF: return */ "\xC3\x94", // O circumflex

        /* case 0xF0: return */ "\xEF\xA3\xBF", // box (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xF1: return */ "\xC3\x92", // O grave
        /* case 0xF2: return */ "\xC3\x9A", // U accent
        /* case 0xF3: return */ "\xC3\x9B", // U circumflex
        /* case 0xF4: return */ "\xC3\x99", // U grave
        /* case 0xF5: return */ "\xC4\xB1", // dotless i ligature (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xF6: return */ "\xCB\x86", // circumflex
        /* case 0xF7: return */ "\xCB\x9C", // tilde
        /* case 0xF8: return */ "\xC2\xAF", // macron
        /* case 0xF9: return */ "\xCB\x98", // breve (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xFA: return */ "\xCB\x99", // raised dot (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xFB: return */ "\xCB\x9A", // ring
        /* case 0xFC: return */ "\xC2\xB8", // cedilla
        /* case 0xFD: return */ "\xCB\x9D", // double acute accent (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xFE: return */ "\xCB\x9B", // ogonek (not in Windows 1252)
        /* case 0xFF: return */ "\xCB\x87", // caron (not in Windows 1252)
    };

    if ( c >= 0x80 )
    {
        return strings[ c - 0x80 ];
    }

    return string( 1, c );
}
```