# mysql data corrupted after changing encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf

I accidentally changed the encoding of a field from UTF-8 to macroman, after switching back to UTF-8, all Chinese characters were scrambled up, is there any chance I can reverse the process? or the change is permanent ?

Comment: Have you checked here?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559659/converting-mac-roman-character-to-equivalent-utf-8

Comment: By "field" you mean a table column?

Comment: yes, by field i meant a column

Comment: Probably the data is destroyed.  But, just in case it is not, please provide `SELECT HEX(col) FROM ...` for a sample. And tell us what Chinese characters it should represent.  If you get is hex `3F`, the Chinese is lost.  Also, what step(s) did yo use when converting to `macroman`?

Comment: did REPAIR TABLE help?