# PHP Create XML-File with "x-mac-roman" encoding

Tags: php, xml, mac-roman

I have to create a xml-file with "x-mac-roman" encoding.

The documentation of the program, I want to use the xml-file with, states:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="x-mac-roman"?>
```

But neither DomDocument nor XMLWriter know this encoding.

How can I proceed? Thank you very much!

Comment: The “official” IANA name for that encoding seems to be `macintosh`, maybe try that. If that doesn’t work, create the document “normally” in UTF-8 maybe, use iconv to translate it into `macintosh` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4723014/10283047), and then fix the wrong `encoding` attribute that will leave via a simple text replace afterwards …?

Comment: Why do you want to create a document using an encoding that your XML tools don't understand? Why not use a more standard encoding that everyone recognizes, like UTF-8?

Comment: @misorude: Thank you very much. I did like you said.

Comment: @MichaelKay I would love to, but the program (MacGiro) required the x-mac-roman encoding.

Comment: Then it's not conformant. Every XML parser is required to recognize UTF-8.