# PHP encoding Umlauts and Spaces in .csv for Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, encoding, special-characters

I have some json data that I need to email to my users as a .csv file.

The following code works as expected for `Hällowörld`, however, once I put a space in there, `Hällo wörld`, the .csv file reads `ÔªøH√§llo w√∂rld` when opened in Excel (for Mac).

```
$temp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:10485760', 'w');
$rows = json_decode('[["Hällowörld"]]'); // -> Hällowörld
//$rows = json_decode('[["Hällo wörld"]]'); // -> ÔªøH√§llo w√∂rld
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $row = array_map(function($cell) {
    return chr(239).chr(187).chr(191).$cell;
  }, $row);
  fputcsv($temp, $row, ';');
}
rewind($temp);
$csv = stream_get_contents($temp);
fclose($temp);
$csv = base64_encode($csv);
// -> post $csv to my email provider's API
```

A few notes:

- My code is in UTF-8
- If I open the file with Apple's numbers or textedit, the content is displayed as expected.
- If I don't do the mapping with `chr(239).chr(187).chr(191).$cell`, I get `H√§llow√∂rld`.
- If instead, I use `mb_convert_encoding($cell, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8')` or `mb_convert_encoding($cell, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8')`, as is often suggested, I get `H‰llowˆrld`.
- The final `base64_encode()` is necessary, because my email provider needs the attachment to be base_64-encoded.

Comment: `chr(239).chr(187).chr(191)` (it reads `Ôªø` in [macintosh encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman)) is `UTF-8` file signature ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)). Try `mb_convert_encoding($cell, 'macintosh', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: That creates an empty file

Comment: Sorry, [_mb-functions_ can't handle `"macintosh"`; use `iconv` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4723014/3439404)

Comment: Thanks, but `return iconv('macintosh', 'UTF-8', $cell);` returns `H‚àö¬ßllo w‚àö‚àÇrld`

Comment: It looks as a double [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! :) Replace the above `foreach` loop with the following:

```
array_unshift($rows, [chr(239).chr(187).chr(191)]);
foreach($rows as $row) {
  fputcsv($f, $row, ',');
}
```