# CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") doesn't work under Excel for Mac

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of VBA code which is used to get subfolders given a path, it works well under `Excel for Windows`:

```
Function GetSubFolders(RootPath As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim sf As Object
    Dim myArr

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(RootPath)
    For Each sf In fld.SUBFOLDERS
        Counter = Counter + 1
        ReDim Preserve Arr(Counter)
        Arr(Counter) = sf.Path
        myArr = GetSubFolders(sf.Path)
    Next
    GetSubFolders = Arr
    Set sf = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Now I would like to run this code under `Excel for Mac` (version: 2011 14.4.1). It gives an error at the line `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. The error message is `Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object`.

Could anyone help me debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileSystemObject is part of the Windows scripting library, which doesn't exist on Mac OSX.

Similar question asked previously:  [How can I install/use "Scripting.FileSystemObject" in Excel 2010 for MAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670420/how-can-i-install-use-scripting-filesystemobject-in-excel-2010-for-mac)

Comment: Please see this [meta question about duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252047/answering-a-duplicate). Duplicates should be flagged as such.