# Enumerating a directory and Inserting Picture's with Unicode file name (mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using MS Office on Mac and I need to enumerate files in a folder and insert them as pictures.

The problem is that the file names contain Unicode characters, and as I am on Mac I [cannot use FileSystemObject library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23448686/) and `Dir()` function [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33685990/) with Unicode characters.

Example file names:

```
HCLL20220419 色块 50x65cm-效果图.jpg
HCLL20220424-2  抽象画 50x65cm-效果图.jpg
```

This code does not work because `Dir` cannot handle these file names:

```vb
Sub insertimages()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim pathtomyfolder As String
    pathtomyfolder = "Path to my folder"

    fname = Dir(pathtomyfolder)

    While fname <> ""
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.insert(pathtofolder & Application.PathSeparator & fname).Select
        fname = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```